# Asymptotics on number of bounded prime gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

It's been over 2 years since the groundbreaking paper by Yitang Zhang in which he has shown that infinitely many prime pairs are by some constant $H$, with $H\leq 70000000$. Over the course of the following year the bound on $H$ has been greatly reduced to $H\leq 246$. However, I have never seen a result which would say anything more about number of such pairs, and I probably wouldn't believe if someone said to me that the methods used don't provide any estimates.

My question here is:

> What is the best known lower bound on the number of prime pairs separated by less than (or equal) a given number $n$? I am particularily interested in $n=246$ (best for which we know there is infinitely many) and some big $n$, like original $70000000$ (for which we might know stronger bounds).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to extract from the current arguments a lower bound of the form $x / (\log x)^{C}$ with $C$ in the order of magnitude of $10^2$

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/q/176875 .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for this link, I think the question can now be marked as a duplicate.