# Number of twin primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

Consider number of twin primes less than $x$. We know that this number less than $\frac{Cx}{\log^2 x}$ for some constant $C$.

Denote by $p_n$ the $n$-th prime number. Do we have the same result about number of prime numbers $p_n<x$ such that $p_{n+1} - p_n < D$ for some constant $D$?

Comment: Yes, in fact one can deduce such results for at least one even integer between 2 and 240 following the recent advances of James Maynard and the subsequent polymath project.

Comment: Can deduce C is about 1.32. $n_{tp}(x)\approx1.32(\pi(x))^{2}x^{-1}\approx1.32x(logx)^{-2}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, and this can be proved in the same way, e.g. by the large sieve or the Selberg sieve. Of course, the constant $C$ will depend on $D$.

For a lower bound (for $D=248$ at the moment), see my response to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176875/lower-bound-for-a-prime-gap-occurring-infinitely-often).

**Added 1.** As GuestPoster pointed out to me, the upper bound $Z(x)\ll x/\log^2 x$ for the number of twin primes up to $x$ was already established by Brun. His original paper is available [here](https://archive.org/details/lecriblederatost00brun). In fact Brun shows $Z(x)<100x/\log^2 x$  for $x>x_0$, see the last display (37) in the paper. No doubt Brun's method works equally well for the original question above, with $100$ being replaced by an effective constant depending on $D$.

**Added 2.** J. R. Chen proved in his paper "On Goldbach's problem and the sieve methods" (Sci. Sinica Ser. A 21 (1978), 701-738.) that the number of solutions of $P-P'=h$ in primes $P'<P<x$ is less than
$$ 7.8342\times \prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\right)\prod_{\substack{p>2\\p\mid h}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p-2}\right)\times\frac{x}{\log^2 x},$$
assuming $x$ is sufficiently large in terms of $h$.
I learned this from a paper of Pintz and Ruzsa (Acta Arith. 109 (2003), 169-194.).

Comment: I am not sure what your "e.g." for "in the same way" means, as wasn't the twin primes upper bound of that form first proven by Brun in 1919/20?

Comment: @GuestPoster: Brun's upper bound was off by a factor of $(\log\log x)^2$ or so. At any rate, knowing that there are few twin primes does not imply aprior that there are few quasi-twin primes as well (with distance less than a thousand, say). Nevertheless, the techniques that provide the upper bound in the original post for the twin primes also provide the same kind of upper bound for the quasi-twin primes (with a different constant). I hope this clarifies.

Comment: No, his first paper was off by that log-log power. A later paper even got the explicit constant $C=100$. Le crible d’Eratosthene et le theoreme de Goldbach. Comptes Rendus Acad. Sci. Paris, 168 (1919), 544-546 announces it, and Le crible d’Eratosthene et le theoreme de Goldbach. Videnselsk. Skr. 1, No. 3 (1920) gets 100.

Comment: @GuestPoster: I looked up Brun's paper, and you are right about his bound (not losing a loglog power). Let me update my post accordingly.

Comment: I think Chen's result is only valid in the asymptotic regime where $x$ is assumed sufficiently large depending on $h$.

Comment: @TerryTao: You are absolutely right, and I updated the text accordingly.